# How does Snipping Tool do this?

Tags: c++, c, windows, user-interface, winapi

I noticed that Snipping Tool (On Windows Vista / 7) has a Toolbar control. I'v used Spy++ and copied its exact styles but when I press down, it does not do like theirs. Theirs stays stuck on the clicked control, indicating that this tool is 'in use' I want to have this effect in my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a NT6 system near me ATM but I think you are just talking about the BSTYLE_CHECK toolbar button style